# Canonical way to represent idea of sum type of records that all extend a "base" record

Tags: functional-programming, purescript, discriminated-union, sealed-class

I'm new to PureScript. I was searching for sealed classes in Purescript to get an idea of how one would implement this, but I don't think I have the necessary PS jargon yet.

What is the canonical way in PureScript to have a bunch of records that extend a "base" record, but then have one sum type representing a "sealed" collection of those.

Something like in Kotlin,

```kotlin
sealed class Glazing(val name: String, val area: Int) {
  class Window(val name: String, val area: Int, val frameMaterial: String): BaseGlazing(name, area)
  class Door(val name: String, val area: Int, val isPreHung: Boolean): BaseGlazing(name, area)
}
```

in TypeScript, you'd probably do something like

```js
interface BaseGlazing { ... }
interface Door extends BaseGlazing { ... }
interface Window extends BaseGlazing { ... }
type Glazing = Door | Window

and then you'd either take `A extends BaseGlazing` or `Glazing` (and use type guards) to do either of those two above functions.
```

Essentially I want a base class (that is technically abstract), things that extend it, and then a sum type/discriminated union of the extensions so that way I can both write, say, `changeName:: Glazing -> Glazing` (premised on the base class having a `name` prop) but also do something like `calculateTotalLightPenetration :: Array Glazing -> Number` (premised on the discriminated union being one of `Door` or `Window` since light penetration will be a different formula for doors vs windows)

Answer (score 3):

The idea of "inheritance" (aka "is-a" relationship) is technically possible to model in PureScript, but it's hard and awkward. And there is a good reason for it: inheritance is almost never (and I am tempted to say "never, period") the most convenient, efficient, or reliable way of modeling the domain. Even OOP apologists tend to recommend aggregation over inheritance these days.

One useful thing to observe is that you don't actually *need* inheritance. What you *need* is to solve some specific problem in your domain, and inheritance is just a solution that you naturally reach for, which is probably informed by your past experience.

And this leads us to an insight: the particular way to model whatever it is you're modeling would depend on what the actual problem is. Chances are, PureScript has a different mechanism for modeling that.

---

But if I base my thinking on the specifics you gave in your question (i.e. the `changeName` and `calculateTotalLightPenetration` functions), I would model it via aggregation: the "glazing" would be the surrounding type, and it would have, as one of its parts, the specific kind of glazing. This would look something like this:

```hs
type Glazing = { name :: String, area :: Int, kind :: GlazingKind }

data GlazingKind = Window { frameMaterial :: String } | Door { isPreHung :: Boolean }

changeName :: Glazing -> Glazing
changeName g = g { name = "new name" }

calculateTotalLightPenetration :: Array Glazing -> Number
calculateTotalLightPenetration gs = sum $ individualPenetration <$> gs
  where
    individualPenetration g = case g.kind of
      Door _ -> 0.3
      Window _ -> 0.5
```

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is if my domain includes, among other things, things that might be made of glass (glazings, windows always have glass; doors sometimes have glass but other times are just opaque barriers) and can be named/described by a user (among many other behaviors),  (1) without writing more boilerplate than necessary, (2) achieve: (a) functions that operate upon `Glazing` and only rely on props of Glazing (like changing `name`); (b) functions that operate upon anything that might be made of glass (light penetration); and (c) functions that can accept as argument only

Comment: *one* of the things. For example, you can rename *any* glazing bc it's a prop of glazing, you can calculate opacity (wood doors without glass are `0`, various glass doors/windows are of varying opacity), or you can calculate something that only pertains to doors, like whether the door is pre-hung.

Your answer solves the first two. If I wanted to only use a "child" type, I would do something like `isPrehung :: Door -> Boolean` right? Your answer from an OOP perspective makes it look like glazing "has a" door, rather than door "is a" glazing. But with PS this is not a good interpretation?

Comment: I guess I expected it to be different because you have something like a Functor, which guarantees an `map` function, but then you have various "implementations" of Functor (Array, Maybe, Identity, etc.), but some of these also "implement" Monad, so you can have a fn that takes Monad. Then some of these are also sum types (Either is monad, also is Left | Right) Hard to explain since I come from languages like TypeScript where types are simulated with interfaces. I sense that I'm tap-dancing around the concept of "traits" like in Rust, but I don't know. In any case, thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Yes, you can model your domain with type classes, but that's going to be way more messy. Type classes are applicable when you want an "open world" - i.e. an ability to add more things "later". But this is not your case, since you say you want a sum type of all possibilities. Plus, with type classes it's hard and awkward to have an array of things.